# Why doesn't the non-degeneracy definition of the metric tensor assure $g(v,v)=0\implies v=0$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

We know that a defining property of the metric tensor is that it is non-degenerate, meaning $\forall u,\, g(v,u)=0\implies v=0$. Yet from a textbook I read that $g(v,v)=0$ does not assure $v=0$. Why is this? Can't we simply let $v=u$ in the definition and obtain $g(v,v)=0\implies v=0$?

Thanks.

Comment: $g(u,v)=0$ implies $v=0$ ONLY IF that first statement is true FOR ALL $u$. In your proof, you are using the fact that $g(u,v)=0$ for a PARTICULAR $u$ (namely $u=v$) to conclude that $v$ should be zero.

Comment: @Prahar， Thanks, I see why now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a question of logic:

Suppose $$g(v,v)= 0 \Longrightarrow v=0 \tag{1} $$ holds. Then we can conclude

$$\forall u:\quad g(u,v)=0  \Longrightarrow v=0 \quad, \tag{2}$$
by choosing $u=v$. However, the converse must not be necessarily true: Even if $(2)$ holds, we cannot conclude from $g(v,v)=0$ *alone* that $v=0$ - the condition in $(2)$ must hold for all $u$.

So while $(2)$ follows from $(1)$, the converse is in general not true. Counter examples are provided in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

On Lorentzian manifolds there is an obvious counter example to your claim, namely null-vectors. Let
$$g = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
be the Minkowski metric in 2D. Consider
$$v= \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
We see that $g(v,v)=0$ although $v \neq 0$. Therefore, your implication is false.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think of [null/lightlike vectors](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lightlike.html) in [SR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity).